# android studio not showing network inspector

Tags: android, android-studio

I saw this documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler

which says we can inspect networks requests and responses via network inspector. But, my android studio not showing this tab. ( I tried `invalidate caches/restart`, but didn't work out)

current android studio version is: **Arctic Fox, 2020.3.1 patch 4**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow this :
go to profiler at the bottom -> starting a new profiling session(make sure your app is running while doing this) -> you will get to see it says Network Profiler has moved-> click network inspector
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Bdl.png)

Comment: It still does not show anything

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem and fixed it.

AndroidManifest.xml

remove `android:sharedUserId` attribute from `<manifest>` element.

I added `android:sharedUserId` for shot plugin to save screenshots.
shot works only with androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml.
No need to add to global AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: SharedUserId indeed turned out to be the culprit in my case as well. According to docs, it's used is strongly discouraged too. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element

Answer (score 0):

From Android studio Electric Eel version,
follow the below steps in the AS navigation bar:

1). Select View > Tool Windows > App Inspection

[image]

2). Select a process, and you might see two tabs here: Database inspector & Network inspector.

3). Navigate to "Network inspector" tab
[image]

For more details: [https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20Network%20Inspector,Network%20Inspector%20from%20the%20tabs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20Network%20Inspector,Network%20Inspector%20from%20the%20tabs).

Answer (score 0):

- You need to select `AppInspection` id it does not appear on the studio

[image]

- Then Select the `AppInspection` in the bottom tab so that the window appears

[image]